# SAX парсинг тегов

Tags: java, xml

Каким образом можно по тексту тегов, которые внутри тега отцовского, узнать какому именно отцу он пренадлежит и выдать все значение внутри отца по одному из этих значений методом SAX?

DOM методом и XPATH уже обрабатывал, нужна помощь именно с SAX.

Ну грубо говоря, пользователь должен ввести `Product1`, а ему должно выдастся:   `Product1` пренадлежит тегу `id` внутри тега `product` и должeн выдастся спискок тип "значения этого тега"("Id", "Name", "Price")+ его значение, ну и как-бы полностю пролистать все что внутри продукта и выдать. Ну это всего лишь пример там должно быть чтоб оно не привзывалсь не к каким-то статчным именам а програма адекватно реагировала на смену всех тегов и добавления новых. Реализовал уже поиск по атрибутам:

```
DefaultHandler handler=new DefaultHandler(){

    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)throws SAXException {
        super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);
        String name= attributes.getValue(textField.getText());


        if(name!=null && !name.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println(name);
        }   

    }
    public void  characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws  SAXException{
        String str="";
        for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
            str+=ch[start+i];
        }if(textField.getText().equals("all")){
        System.out.println(str);}
    }
};

SAXParserFactory factory= SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
parser.parse(new File("src\\data\\products.xml"), handler);
```

Данные:

```
<products>
<product name="eee" price="122">
    <id>p01</id>
    <name>Product1</name>
    <price>100</price>
</product>
<product name="pp" price="123">
    <id>p02</id>
    <name>Product2</name>
    <price>200</price>
</product>
<product name="rr" price="124">
    <id>p03</id>
    <name>Product3</name>
    <price>300</price>
</product>
<product name="rrr" price="125">
    <id>p04</id>
    <name>Product4</name>
    <price>400</price>
</product>
```

Comment: Не стоит делать в заголовке пометки вроде "ещё не решено". Здесь это не принято.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class SAXHandler extends DefaultHandler {
    private final String query;
    private String currentTagName;
    private Product currentProduct;

    private static class Product {
        private String id;
        private String name;
        private int price;

        public void setId(String id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setPrice(String price) {
            this.price = Integer.parseInt(price);
        }

        public int getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Id: %s\nName: %s\nPrice: %d\n", id, name, price);
        }
    }

    public SAXHandler(String query) {
        this.query = query;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        currentTagName = qName;

        if(qName.equals("product")) {
            currentProduct = new Product();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if(qName.equals("product")) {
            if (query.equals(currentProduct.getName()))
                System.out.println(currentProduct);

            currentProduct = null;
        }
        currentTagName = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        if(currentProduct == null)
            return;

        String tagContent = new String(ch, start, length).trim();

        if ("id".equals(currentTagName))
            currentProduct.setId(tagContent);

        if ("name".equals(currentTagName))
            currentProduct.setName(tagContent);

        if ("price".equals(currentTagName))
            currentProduct.setPrice(tagContent);
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        if (args.length < 1) {
            System.err.println("Введите имя искомого продукта");
            return;
        }

        try {
            SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();

            SAXHandler handler = new SAXHandler(args[0]);
            saxParser.parse("test.xml", handler);
        }
        catch(SAXException ex) {}
        catch(ParserConfigurationException ex) {}
        catch(IOException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) но Ну это всего лишь пример там должно быть чтоб оно не привзывалсь не к каким-то статчным именам тип id name а програма адекватно реагировала на смену всех тегов и добавления новых. То есть полноценный парсер

Comment: Чудес не бывает. Вам придётся полностью реализовывать конечный автомат в коде sax-обработчика - каждое состояние и все переходы для определённого формата xml-документа и требуемой логики парсинга. Изменится формат входных или выходных данных, придётся переписать код.

Comment: я не где не могу найти инфу в инете как это можно зделать можете кинуть ссылку?

Comment: Пример в моём ответе показывает как и может служить отправной точкой для разработки более сложных парсеров. Хорошо SAX-парсинг описан в [этом учебнике](https://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/1204719/).

Answer (score 0):

Единственный способ определить родителя при использовании SAX -- сохранить иерархию тегов в процессе чтения документа. Возможно, для Вашей задачи больше подойдет DOM-парзер (см. `DocumentBuilderFactory` и `DocumentBuilder`).

Comment: К сожалению у меня задача такая. А каким образом можно сохранить иерархию тегов в процессе чтения документа SAX можете продемонстрировать пожалуйста если не лень) Или кинте ссылку на статью.